# C++ specialize a template class to take an additional template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Is it possible to specialize a template class to take additional template parameters ?

For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct X {
  void foo() { cerr << "Generic" << endl;}
};


template <>
template <bool b>
struct X<int> {
  void foo() { cerr << "Specialization" << endl;}
};
```

I could not make the above work with g++, but maybe there is some trick which will make this work.

Edit: I don't want to move the template `<bool b>` to the base template X, because it is feature of only `X<int>.`
If I have to, is there  a way I can allow users to not have to specify any values for it? I would really like
an approach that does not go down this route.

Comment: Have you heard of partial template specialization?

Comment: "*If I have to, is there a way I can allow users to not have to specify any values for it?*" Yes -- default template parameters. E.g. `template<typename T, bool = false>`.

Comment: As @ildjarn said, you can -- but I'd caution that in most cases it's better to use some type other than bool. `mytempl<doThis>` vs. `myempl<doThat>` is usually more meaningful than `mytempl<true>` vs. `mytempl<false>`.

Answer (score 2):

You could change your primary template to accept a proxy traits class instead:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    typedef typename T::type type;

    // work with "type"

    void static print() { std::cout << T::message << std::endl; }
}
```

Then define the trait class:

```
template <typename T>
struct traits
{
    typedef T type;
    static const char * const message  = "Generic";
};
```

Now you can instantiate `Foo<traits<double>>` and `Foo<traits<int>>`, and you can encapsulate additional behaviour into the traits class, which you can specialize as needed.

```
template <>
struct traits<int>
{
    typedef int type;
    static const char * const message = "Specialized";
};
```

Comment: One doesn't have to change the primary template for that. Just make a specialization that accepts `traits<whatever>`.